# How to define the Pointcut(s) for annotation directly on method and on another annotation (which is then used on a method)?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop

I am trying to figure out how to define Pointcuts and how to handle multiple annotations using spring AOP.

I have the following custom annotations:

**@RequiresNonBlank**

```java
@Retention (RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target (value = {ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Documented
public @interface RequiresNonBlank {
  String value();
  Class<? extends StuffException> throwIfInvalid();
}
```

and

**@RequiresNonBlankDummy**

```java
@Retention (RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target (value = {ElementType.METHOD})
@Documented
@RequiresNonBlank (
    value = "T(com.stuff.exceptions.annotation.TestDummyValueHolder).value",
    throwIfInvalid = TestDummyStuffException.class
)
@interface RequiresNonBlankDummy {
}
```

and I have the following dummy controller:

**TestDummyController**

```java
@Component
public class TestDummyController {
  @RequiresNonBlank (
      value = "T(com.stuff.exceptions.annotation.TestDummyValueHolder).value",
      throwIfInvalid = TestDummyStuffException.class
  )
  public boolean methodWithRequiresNonBlankAnnotation() {
    return true;
  }

  @RequiresNonBlankDummy
  public boolean methodWithRequiresNonBlankDummyAnnotation() {
    return true;
  }

  @RequiresNonBlankDummy
  @RequiresNonBlank (
      value = "T(com.stuff.exceptions.annotation.TestDummyValueHolder).anotherValue",
      throwIfInvalid = TestDummyStuffException.class
  )
  public boolean methodWithMultipleRequiresNonBlankAnnotation() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

My `TestDummyValueHolder` is a class, which only contains two Strings (`value` and `anotherValue`) and their corresponding getters and setters.

I want to define one or multiple pointcuts (`@Pointcut`), which would handle one or multiple / stacked `@RequiresNonBlank` on a method ("derived" annotations such as `@RequiresNonBlankDummy` should be taken into account).

My aspect handler currently looks like this:

**RequiresNonBlankAspect**

```java
@Component
@Aspect
@Slf4j
public class RequiresNonBlankAspect {
  private static final String REQUIRES_NON_BLANK_FQPN =
      "com.stuff.exceptions.annotation.RequiresNonBlank";
  @Before("execution(@" + REQUIRES_NON_BLANK_FQPN + " * *(..)) && @annotation(annotation)")
  public void evaluatePreconditionItself(JoinPoint joinPoint, RequiresNonBlank annotation) {
    evaluatePrecondition(joinPoint, annotation);
  }

  @Before("execution(@(@" + REQUIRES_NON_BLANK_FQPN + " *) * *(..)) && @annotation(annotation)")
  public void evaluatePreconditionOnAnnotation(JoinPoint joinPoint, RequiresNonBlank annotation) {
    evaluatePrecondition(joinPoint, annotation);
  }

  private void evaluatePrecondition(JoinPoint joinPoint, RequiresNonBlank annotation) {
    try {
      Objects.requireNonNull(annotation);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
      log.error("No annotation found!", e);
    }

    ExpressionParser elParser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    Expression expression = elParser.parseExpression(annotation.value());

    String expressionToEvaluate = (String) expression.getValue(joinPoint.getArgs());
    log.info("value to check: {}", expressionToEvaluate);

    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(expressionToEvaluate)) {
      try {
        throw annotation.throwIfInvalid().getConstructor().newInstance();
      } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException
          | NoSuchMethodException e) {
        log.error("Could not throw the exception configured!", e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However: `annotationOnAnnotation(...)` does not work. `annotationItself` however does.

I have the following Test:

**RequiresNonBlankTest**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ActiveProfiles (profiles = "test")
@RunWith (SpringRunner.class)
public class RequiresNonBlankTest {

  @Autowired
  private TestDummyController controller;

  @Test (expected = TestDummyStuffException.class)
  public void testRequiresNonBlank_valueIsNull() {
    TestDummyValueHolder.setValue(null);
    controller.methodWithRequiresNonBlankAnnotation();
  }

  @Test
  public void testRequiresNonBlank_valueIsNotNull() {
    TestDummyValueHolder.setValue("value: non-null");
    assertThat(controller.methodWithRequiresNonBlankAnnotation(), equalTo(true));
  }

  @Test (expected = TestDummyStuffException.class)
  public void testRequiresNonBlankDummy_valueIsNull() {
    TestDummyValueHolder.setValue(null);
    controller.methodWithRequiresNonBlankDummyAnnotation();
  }

  @Test
  public void testRequiresNonBlankDummy_valueIsNotNull() {
    TestDummyValueHolder.setValue("value: non-null");
    assertThat(controller.methodWithRequiresNonBlankDummyAnnotation(), equalTo(true));
  }
}
```

However: test `testRequiresNonBlankDummy_valueIsNull()` fails.

---

I also would like to know how to not only react to annotations on annotations on a method (see `@RequiresNonBlankDummy`), but also to what I have in `TestDummyController#methodWithMultipleRequiresNonBlankAnnotation` (stacked / multiple annotations). Is this possible and if so, how?

I am using Spring Boot and Spring AOP. I have tried using `AnnotationUtils` and `AnnotationElementUtils`, but I at least from what I can tell it did not help. Please help me or give me a hint on how to solve this.

---

**Edit** (15.08.2021):

**TestDummyValueHolder**

```java
public class TestDummyValueHolder {
  private static String value;
  private static String anotherValue;

  public static String getValue() {
    return TestDummyValueHolder.value;
  }

  public static void setValue(String value) {
    TestDummyValueHolder.value = value;
  }

  public static String getAnotherValue() {
    return TestDummyValueHolder.anotherValue;
  }

  public static void setAnotherValue(String anotherValue) {
    TestDummyValueHolder.anotherValue = anotherValue;
  }
}
```

**StuffException** is pretty generic. In fact you could replace it with any Exception, which has a no-args constructor.
I have also updated the aspect handler (**RequiresNonBlankAspect**) to be like what @kriegaex mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Writing a new answer after the OP updated his question, correcting something that was wrong in the beginning. Now the old answer does not fit anymore.*

OK, the remaining problems are:

- Now that we changed from chaining two pointcuts with `||` to having two separate pointcuts, the annotation binding works more reliably. Please note, though:

  - For method `methodWithMultipleRequiresNonBlankAnnotation` which carries both the normal and the meta annotation, both advices are triggered, i.e. something that maybe you only expect to happen once, now actually happens twice.
  - OTOH, you might actually want two advices firing, because there are two different SpEL expressions `T(de.scrum_master.spring.q68785567.TestDummyValueHolder).anotherValue`  (in `@RequiresNonBlank`) and `T(de.scrum_master.spring.q68785567.TestDummyValueHolder).value` (in the annotation of `@RequiresNonBlankDummy`), then this is actually better. It depends on your requirement.
- Your usage of `@annotation(annotation)` in combination with the parameter binding `RequiresNonBlank annotation` stops the advice from firing for `@RequiresNonBlankDummy` (method `methodWithRequiresNonBlankDummyAnnotation`), because the two annotation types are incompatible and there is no such thing as one annotation type extending another or implementing interfaces. So all you are left with in this case is to use the poinctuts without parameter binding and find the annotations via reflection from inside the advice methods.

---

**Update:** OK, I made the assumption that in case of both a direct and a meta annotation you want both advices firing. The solution then looks like this:

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q68785567;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.expression.Expression;
import org.springframework.expression.ExpressionParser;
import org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Objects;

@Component
@Aspect
//@Slf4j
public class RequiresNonBlankAspect {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequiresNonBlankAspect.class.getName());
  private static final String REQUIRES_NON_BLANK_FQPN =
    "de.scrum_master.spring.q68785567.RequiresNonBlank";
  private ExpressionParser elParser = new SpelExpressionParser();

  @Before("execution(@" + REQUIRES_NON_BLANK_FQPN + " * *(..)) && @annotation(requiresNonBlank)")
  public void evaluatePreconditionItself(JoinPoint joinPoint, RequiresNonBlank requiresNonBlank) {
    log.info("[DIRECT] " + joinPoint + " -> " + requiresNonBlank);
    evaluatePrecondition(joinPoint, requiresNonBlank);
  }

  @Before("execution(@(@" + REQUIRES_NON_BLANK_FQPN + " *) * *(..))")
  public void evaluatePreconditionOnAnnotation(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    RequiresNonBlank requiresNonBlank = getRequiresNonBlankMeta(joinPoint);
    log.info("[META]   " + joinPoint + " -> " + requiresNonBlank);
    evaluatePrecondition(joinPoint, requiresNonBlank);
  }

  private RequiresNonBlank getRequiresNonBlankMeta(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    RequiresNonBlank requiresNonBlank = null;
    Method method = ((MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature()).getMethod();
    Annotation[] annotations = method.getAnnotations();
    for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
      RequiresNonBlank requiresNonBlankMeta = annotation.annotationType().getAnnotation(RequiresNonBlank.class);
      if (requiresNonBlankMeta != null) {
        requiresNonBlank = requiresNonBlankMeta;
        break;
      }
    }
    return requiresNonBlank;
  }

  public void evaluatePrecondition(JoinPoint joinPoint, RequiresNonBlank requiresNonBlank) {
    try {
      Objects.requireNonNull(requiresNonBlank);
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e) {
      log.error("No annotation found!", e);
    }

    Expression expression = elParser.parseExpression(requiresNonBlank.value());
    String expressionToEvaluate = (String) expression.getValue(joinPoint.getArgs());
    log.info("Evaluated expression: " + expressionToEvaluate);
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(expressionToEvaluate)) {
      try {
        throw requiresNonBlank.throwIfInvalid().getConstructor().newInstance();
      }
      catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
        log.error("Could not throw the exception configured!", e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Update 2:** [This gist](https://gist.github.com/kriegaex/7fb3ff5313fe089a503f24363849557e) is my take on the new requirement of repeatable annotations, multiple meta annotations and mixing them, but using on-board Java means instead of Spring annotation utilities in order to also make it work in native AspectJ applications outside of a Spring context. BTW, I renamed some classes and methods because for me your names were too similar and somewhat inexpressive.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I tried what you offered (I will also definitely checkout your other answer), but the `RequiresNonBlankTest#testRequiresNonBlankDummy_valueIsNull` test is still failing, because the expected Exception has not been thrown. Apparently it does not recognize the `@RequiresNonBlank(...)` annotation in the `@RequiresNonBlankDummy` annotation on the controller method (`TestDummyController#methodWithRequiresNonBlankDummyAnnotation`). All other tests work, probably due to `evaluatePreconditionItself` kicking in properly. Do you have any other idea of what to do?

Comment: Oh sorry, I did not run your test but created a little main class running the methods and did not compare the log output to your tests thoroughly. I also made a mistake to think that your second pointcut was wrong, because my other answer you commented was not about nested annotations but about class vs. method annotations. So I thought that you actually want something else, because you were mixing up two topics. Furthermore, you edited your question after I already answered, correcting something that I mentioned as an error before. Now my answer does not fit anymore. I need to rephrase it.

Comment: OK, please read my updated answer and comment of what should happen in case of `methodWithMultipleRequiresNonBlankAnnotation` with the double annotation: Should one annotation be preferred? If so, direct or meta? Or should both advices fire, so you get reactions to both SpEL expressions? Moreover, can you deal with the reflection, getting the (meta) annotations from the method instance, or do you need help with that? P.S.: This is pretty contrived. I guess, code like that is hard to maintain or understand for people other than yourself (or me as kind of an AOP expert, for that matter).

Comment: **Update:** OK, I made the assumption that in case of both a direct and a meta annotation you want both advices firing. See my answer to an example aspect.

Comment: Thank you! I will check it out in a hour or so (am on my way home), but what I wonder is: if I had multiple such annotations on a method, would it be able to find the annotation causing the pointcut? I might want to have several `RequiresNonBlank` annotations (or a combination of `RequiresNonBlank` and `RequiresNonBlank*` annotations) where each one evaluates a different expression. Judging from the `for-each` inside `getRequiresNonBlankMeta` I don't think I'd be able to find that particular annotation, would I?

Comment: Again, thank you! I tested it. It works beautifully, except if I have `@RequiredNonBlankDummy` and `@RequiredNonBlankAnotherDummy` (which is an exact copy of `@RequiredNonBlankDummy`, except it evaluates `anotherValue` instead of just `value`) on a controller method. It seems it is not getting triggered on every "derived" `@RequiredNonBlank` annotation, but only on the first one. If there was a way to fix this, I'd be entirely happy, but something tells me it's not possible, because in `getRequiresNonBlankMeta` we are returning after the first result - or am I missing something?

Comment: Excuse me for one more post please. Here's my current, slightly anonymized set of files: https://gist.github.com/voronin-de/7925345c64b6dad27a7a718c1bfe47be . It should contain all relevant classes and relationships. I finally got it to work the way I wanted (several META-annotations) by using `@Repeatable`. It's not perfect, but it covers my use cases I'd say. Thank you once again for your help!

Comment: You basically did what I would have recommended you to do: remove the `break` statement in the loop after finding the first meta annotationand collecting all found annotations in a collection instead. Same goes for `@Repeatable`. Of course it is also OK to use Spring's annotation utilities if you are 100% sure you never want to do anything similar outside of a Spring context. I use native AspectJ outside of Spring most of the time, so I implemented the annotation search manually. Whatever you prefer...

Comment: [This gist](https://gist.github.com/kriegaex/7fb3ff5313fe089a503f24363849557e) is my take on the new requirement of repeatable annotations, multiple meta annotations and mixing them, but using on-board Java means instead of Spring annotation utilities in order to also make it work in native AspectJ applications outside of a Spring context. BTW, I renamed some classes and methods because for me your names were too similar and somewhat inexpressive.

Comment: Thank you! Your gist is fantastic and definitely somewhat cleaner than mine and though I've definitely heard your concern in regards to using Spring-AOP-related utils (like I have), my library already requires spring anyway, because it contains exception-handling (like `@ControllerAdvice`) anyway. People, who don't use Spring, would need to remove a few annotations anyway. So... Still: big thanks for your patience!