# How to write Pointcut expression for Spring AOP to weave meta-annotation in any level of deepness?

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop, pointcut

If I have Annotation:

```java
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD})
public @interface Loggable {
  enum LogLevel {
    ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, TRACE;
  }

  LogLevel value() default DEBUG;
}
```

and trying to use it as target marker of Spring AOP aspect joinpoint marker, it works well for some aspect, weaved by that composite pointcut:

```java
@Aspect
class LoggableAspect {
  @Pointcut("within(@Loggable *)")
  void aClass() {}

  //@Pointcut("@annotation(Loggable)") - in straight-forward case it works too!
  @Pointcut("execution(@Loggable * *(..))")
  void method() {}

  @Around("method() || aClass()")
  Object aroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {...}
}
```

In other words, it *works well as "straight-forward" annotation usage*, when I write code like this:

```java
@Component
public class Abc {

  @Loggable
  public String method(int x) {
    return "string: " + x;
  }
}
```

But in case of META-annotation...:

```java
@Loggable(INFO)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Log {
}
```

...it doesn't work for example, in that code:

```java
@Component
public class Abc {

  @Log // doesn't work! :(
  public String method(int x) {
    return "string: " + x;
  }
}
```

Certainly, I can write yet another pointcut for *that particular case of 2-level deepness*:

```java
//...

@Pointcut("execution(@(@Loggable *) * *(..))")
void metaMethod() {}

@Around("method() || metaMethod() || aClass()")
Object aroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {...}
```

and it will work, but I want universal solution, working on *any level of deepness* - 3, 4, 5... Is it possible for that style of AOP?

P.S. [That issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011089/aspectj-pointcut-for-all-methods-of-a-class-with-specific-annotation#answer-27565069):

```
execution(public * ((@Transactional *)+).*(..))
```

looks like exactly right solution, but unfortunately, it doesn't work in my case. I think, it's possible only as AspectJ solution (in *.aj files) - not for Spring AOP. Am I right?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer to your question, even though you might not like it, is: Neither Spring AOP as a syntactical subset of AspectJ nor native AspectJ provide a dedicated syntax to achieve what you wish to do. The best you can actually do is to use a nested syntax like you suggested yourself and use a reasonable number of nesting levels.

In my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67005346/1082681) you find solutions for both class- and method-level meta annotations.

---

**Update:** You misunderstood what

```java
execution(public * ((@Transactional *)+).*(..))
```

means, even though the answer you linked to explains it:

> Matches the execution of any public method in a type with the `Transactional` annotation, or any subtype of a type with the `Transactional` annotation.

So this syntax is about class inheritance, not about meta annotation nesting. It means that if you have `@Transational class Parent`, it would match `class Child extends Parent` and `class Grandchild extends Child` etc. The syntax should also work in Spring AOP, but that does not solve your problem.

Comment: Thanx, @kriegaex ! It helps a lot.