# Executing Spring AOP aspects for annotations aliased with @AliasFor

Tags: java, spring, aop

The idea is to create annotations hierarchy (similar to `@Service`, `@Component` etc) using `@AliasFor` annotation. This should give me the possibility to define aspect, that would execute on parent annotation, and every alias of it. But somehow it doesn't work for me.

`@ComponentScan` is fine, `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` is set.

Example:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface ParentAnnotation {
}
```

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@ParentAnnotation
public @interface ChildAnnotation {

    @AliasFor(annotation = ParentAnnotation.class)
    String value() default "";
}
```

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class EventRecorderAspect {

    @Around("@annotation(com.example.ParentAnnotation)")
    public void exampleMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        // This should be executed for both @ParentAnnotation and @ChildAnnotation
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
public class ExampleController {
    @ChildAnnotation // This should result in executing aspect for every implementation
    String controllerMethod(); 
}
```

UPDATE:
I've updated code, as @M.Deinum suggested in a comment below. But it still doesnt work.

Comment: The `ChildAnnotation` isn't marked with `@ParentAnnotation` so how should that work?

Comment: Geez, I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: OK, after refactor it still doesn't work. Aspect triggers for parent annotation, but not for child.

Comment: It needs to be `@Inherited` as well afaik and Spring itself has dedicated support for composed annotations, so not sure if that would work with a regular Aspectj.

Comment: @M.Deinum, `@Inherited` only applies to annotations on classes inherited by other classes, neither to annotations on interfaces or to meta annotations, nor to annotations on methods or other elements.

Comment: @kriegaex So is there a way to somehow inherit annotations from interface method to class method? I'm speaking about example wher `ExampleController` implements interface, which containts method annotated with `@ChildAnnotation` and O would like to execute this aspect for any method from any inerface, that is annotated as `@ChildAnnotation`

Comment: I updated my answer in order to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AspectJ pointcut matching syntax, a subset of which is used by Spring AOP, is ignorant of meta annotations, even though withing the Spring framework as such there is support for it in other places. I think the closest you can get to specifying meta annotations in your pointcut is to do it explicitly up to the nesting level you require. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67005346/1082681) for examples showing the syntax variants for both

- class-level, e.g. `within(@(@com.example.ParentAnnotation *) *)`,
- method-level, e.g. `execution(@(@com.example.ParentAnnotation *) * *(..))`

annotations.

---

**Update:** *@Ariel Grabijas* asked in a follow-up comment:

> So is there a way to somehow inherit annotations from interface method to class method?

Not in Java and also not by means of Spring AOP. But there is a [workaround using native AspectJ inter-type definitions (ITD)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42607016/1082681).